# ignore character from string in order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Is there a way to remove characters like `-` or `a` from being included when sorting using `ORDER BY`? I ask because I am using `order by LENGTH(name), name`
Which gets me close but not right. It outputs like so:

`8.2-11
8.2-12
8.2-13
8.2-14
8.2-13-A`

Which I understand because 8.2-13-A is longer than 8.2-13 so it will be at the end. Can I ignore all special characters and characters so the two `8.2-13`'s are right after each other?

Comment: I have not used it, but MySQL has a `REGEXP` function that uses regular expressions. You could read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) or similar sites if you need help with this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Value, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Value, '.', 1) as R1, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Value`, '.', -1), '-', 1) as r2, 
if(concat('',(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Value, '-', -1)) * 1) =0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Value`, '-', -2), '-', 1),  SUBSTRING_INDEX(Value, '-', -1))  as r3,
if(concat('',(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Value, '-', -1)) * 1) = 0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Value, '-', -1),  '')  as r4
FROM Table1 
Order by lpad(r1,2,0), lpad(r2,2,0), lpad(r3,2,0), r4
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/675ea/1)

Comment: That worked for the most part but now the ordering is off for length so it goes: `8.2-1, 8.2-10, 8.2-11, 8.2-2, 8.2-20, 8.2-24, 8.2-24-A, 8.2-3` and so on.